# Firebase getValue(.class) returning null

Tags: android, firebase

My firebase code returns null when accessing the getValue(____.class) functions even if i have the right code and i am getting the values from getValue() function.Can access everything from firebase but it returns null values everytime

Have Tried more or less every answer here but got no success.

```
  databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                list.clear();

                for (DataSnapshot childsnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    meters = childsnapshot.getValue(meterDetails.class);

                    list.add(meters);

                }
```

Here's the .class code

```
public class meterDetails {
    public String name;
    public String unit;
    public String value;
    public String time;

    public meterDetails(String Value, String Time, String Unit, String Name) {
        this.value = Value;
        this.time = Time;
        this.unit = Unit;
        this.name = Name;


    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setUnit(String unit) {
        this.unit = unit;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public meterDetails() {

    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }


    public String getUnit() {
        return unit;
    }


    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }


    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you share your firebase database screenshot please.

Comment: Please add your database structure. Please also responde with @AlexMamo

Answer (score 1):

Usually this happens because some of your [Firebase database key](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data) does not match the Java pojo class field name, witch it is suppose to be mapped to in your case the `meterDetails` fields name.

Double check name

Here are some things often overseen:

> Firebase rules are missing, the default is to block
>
> Forgot to download the google-services.json
>
> Spelling error in keys names vs code
>
> the marshal Java pojo has wrong method declaration or missing the set
>   method

Answer (score 0):

Try like this -

```
String image = childSnapshot.getId() + ""; 
String image = childSnapshot.child("yourkey").getValue() + "";
```